# How do I use hyphen in namespacing?

Tags: php, namespaces, yii2

I am using `https://packagist.org/packages/bitdevelopment/yii2-validators` , a word count validation in Yii2, but I am getting

```
>PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
    syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ';'
    \bitdevelopment\yii2-validators\WordValidator;
```

How do I use this `yii2` `validator` ?

Comment: You don't, `bitdevelopment\yii2validators\WordValidator;`

Comment: @DamienPirsy Thanks. I guess it's usage page would need to me updated..    http://imgur.com/pE1597w

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot use hypen(-) in namespace. As Class naming convention don't accept hypen, you have to use underscore. See the namespace convention [here](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md).