# Unexpected hyphen in namespace

Tags: php

Error coming up saying

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ';

alluding to

```
use Firebase\php-jwt\src\ExpiredException;
```

i pulled the file from git so not sure if it would be wise to rename the files

Comment: @Arun, what more detail do you need? There's a `-` in a namespace.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38245855/3578036

Comment: The name of a namespace is a regular identifier. It can start with a letter or an underscore (`_`) and it can contain only letters, underscores and digits. Dashes (`-`) are not allowed.

Comment: I don't think that is the namespace... I think that is the name of the file. Try `use Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the location of the file, not the namespace.
Try this instead:

```
use Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException;
```