# Symfony 4 & Zoho SKD 2.0

Tags: symfony, auth0, zoho

Hey guys I am new to Symfony 4 , I am trying to use the Zoho 2.0 SDK to connect to their API & push data from another site to a custom field.

I installed the Zoho SDK using:

```
composer require zohocrm/php-sdk
```

It installed successfully into my vendors folder.

I added it to my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use zohocrm\php-sdk;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

But it gives me an error saying it cannot find the file.

Does any one know or have used the Zoho php sdk with Symfony?

This is the guide I am following:
https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/developer/server-side-sdks/php.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use hyphen `-` in namespace. That is why `use zohocrm\php-sdk;` is invalid. For more info about this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245337/how-do-i-use-hyphen-in-namespacing?answertab=active#tab-top).

> But it gives me an error saying it cannot find the file.

I don't think this is the error you get. You clearly get the following error:

```
(1/1) ParseError
syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ',' or ';'

in HomeController.php line 6
```

The main problem is you are not using classes correctly. Refer to [classes Hierarchy](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/developer/server-side-sdks/php.html#Class_Hierarchy) to import the appropriate class for use.

For example, I want to use `ZCRMProfileCategory`. Find below working controller code with this class imported.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use ZCRMProfileCategory;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , but would I need to find every single reference for that folder & rename it ?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean but I don't think you need to rename anything. Specified classes will autoload when you put `use ClassName;` at top.

Comment: I think `ZCRMRestClient` is the main class that you need. Just import it and start using it via `use ZCRMRestClient;`

Comment: Thank you , I thought you had to put "use zohocrm\php-sdk" on top. 
My mistake.

Comment: This API is god awful to setup.